# Yii2 validators don't show message

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

```
// Some other validation rules
[['FILE_BLOB'], 'file' , 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024, 'message' => 'Here goes my message'],
//Some more validation rules
```

Well my problem is that validator works fine, but it shows it's inbuilt errorMessage in case i want to upload bigger files. Not the one that i specified in `'message' => 'Here goes my message'`

And how can i get my own errorMessage in case there are 2 validators?!

```
[['FILE_BLOB'], 'file' , 'extensions' => ['pdf','text'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024],
```

I guess the easy way would be to split  validations like this:

```
[['FILE_BLOB'], 'file' , 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024],
[['FILE_BLOB'], 'file' , 'extensions' => ['pdf','text']],
```

But 1st i need to get to work these messages.

EDIT:

Problem solved. Need to be more careful with reading documentation.
For custom message with file size need to use `'tooBig'` or `'tooSmall'`, but for extension custom message need to use `'wrongExtension'`.

Comment: why peolpe do not read the documentations before asking questions :|

Comment: i read, but as i already stated, i was too much focused on property - `'message'`. I didn't even considered that there can be another thing that i need to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `tooBig` and `tooSmall` property:

```
[['FILE_BLOB'], 'file' , 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024, 'tooBig' => 'message when file size is large'],
```

For more details refer [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-numbervalidator.html#$tooBig-detail)

Comment: Thanks, i just found that myself :) I was too focused on that `'message'`